# Javascript: tracking touch events without .preventDefault() call

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch-event

I'd like to track fingers in whatever mobile browser, without canceling the default behavior (which would be page scroll).

So I'm doing the following:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (ev) {
  // fingers position tracking ode
}, false);
```

Now, if I want to continuously track the touchmoves, I have to call ev.preventDefault() in that function, which also disables the scrolling of the page. If I don't invoke this, I'll only get one touchmove event fired after which I can move my finger however long I want, - no other touchmove events will follow (until I release my finger and start a new touch/move sequence again that is).

My question basically is: how do I continuously track the fingers on the screen (bound to browser 'window'), without interfering with default browser behavior. I want to believe it is possible somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your best bet is to take over the scrolling your self. There is fortunately a plugin for that http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/